# Python Tkinter scrollbar arrows greyed out

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbars

I got a little problem with my scrollbars. Functionally everything's working fine. Scrollbars appear, react on inserting to text widgets and scrolling works. But right after starting the application, arrow buttons of all scrollbars are greyed out until I resize my application window. Is there anything basically wrong about my frames in grid setup? I divided into quarters, Upper Left (UL), Upper Right (UR), Lower Left (LL), Lower Right(LR).

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *

class findhash_tk(Tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):

        self.frameUL = Tkinter.LabelFrame(self, text="Upper left")   
        self.frameUL.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=2, pady=2)

        self.frameUR = Tkinter.LabelFrame(self, text="Upper right")   
        self.frameUR.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=2, pady=2)

        self.frameLL = Tkinter.LabelFrame(self, text="Lower left")   
        self.frameLL.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=2, pady=2)

        self.frameLR = Tkinter.LabelFrame(self, text="Lower right")   
        self.frameLR.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=2, pady=2)

        self.scrollbarUR = Tkinter.Scrollbar(self.frameUR, orient='vertical')
        self.scrollbarUR.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)     

        self.textBoxUR = Tkinter.Text(self.frameUR)
        self.textBoxUR.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbarUR.set)
        self.textBoxUR.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)

        self.scrollbarUR.config(command=self.textBoxUR.yview)

        self.scrollbarLLV = Tkinter.Scrollbar(self.frameLL, orient='vertical')
        self.scrollbarLLV.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)

        self.scrollbarLLH = Tkinter.Scrollbar(self.frameLL, orient='horizontal')
        self.scrollbarLLH.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W+E)

        self.textBoxLL = Tkinter.Text(self.frameLL)
        self.textBoxLL.config(wrap="none", yscrollcommand=self.scrollbarLLV.set, xscrollcommand=self.scrollbarLLH.set)
        self.textBoxLL.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)

        self.scrollbarLLV.config(command=self.textBoxLL.yview)
        self.scrollbarLLH.config(command=self.textBoxLL.xview)

        self.scrollbarLRV = Tkinter.Scrollbar(self.frameLR, orient='vertical')
        self.scrollbarLRV.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)

        self.scrollbarLRH = Tkinter.Scrollbar(self.frameLR, orient='horizontal')
        self.scrollbarLRH.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W+E)

        self.textBoxLR = Tkinter.Text(self.frameLR)
        self.textBoxLR.config(wrap="none", yscrollcommand=self.scrollbarLRV.set, xscrollcommand=self.scrollbarLRH.set)
        self.textBoxLR.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)

        self.scrollbarLRV.config(command=self.textBoxLR.yview)
        self.scrollbarLRH.config(command=self.textBoxLR.xview)

        for x in range(50): 
            self.textBoxUR.insert(END, str(x) + "\n")

        for x in range(50): 
            self.textBoxLL.insert(END, str(x) + "\n")

        for x in range(50): 
            self.textBoxLR.insert(END, str(x) + "\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = findhash_tk(None)
    app.title('Test App')
    app.mainloop()
```

[Initial state of gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlJNU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick a `self.update()` after:

```
self.textBoxUR.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)
```

Oddly enough further down will not work (some scrollbars will be greyed out, or left bottom horizontal will be colored while it shouldn't). This will fix it for you, but it kind of looks like a bug.

**EDIT**
As OP mentions this is not consistent, and weird anyway. A workaround, after initialize() put:

```
self.wm_geometry("+4000+4000")
self.after(500,lambda:self.wm_geometry("+10+10"))
```

This is dirty, but forces the refresh in windows by placing the window out of screen (if your screen is bigger than 4000 pixel wow, but you can increase) and after half a second moves it back. This look like a weird issue, and on Linux doesn't happen (though color is greyish there always).

Comment: I tried putting `self.update()` below which didn't work.
Putting it where you propose still leaves "LL" horizontal scrollbar arrows grey.

Comment: Both horizontal scrollbars (that's bottom down right?) are supposed to be grey - there's nothing to scroll. Do you want to change this behavior?

Comment: No, not at all. But it's inconsistent, with your solution all arrows are shown black, also lower right's horizontal bar. Only lower left's one stays grey.

Comment: In Linux there is no color change, I think this may be a windows thing. I'll edit a work around in the solution, but post a bug to the tkinter team.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this bug with other widgets besides Text.  The solution I've come up with looks nicer as the window doesn't flicker as it's moved offscreen and back again.  The solution below detects when the Scrollbar changes from a disabled state to an active state or vice versa and destroys and recreates the Scrollbar.

```
from tkinter import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()

    ###

    badframe = Frame(root)
    badframe.grid(row=0, column=0)

    badtext = Text(badframe)
    badtext.grid(row=0, column=0)

    badscrollbar = Scrollbar(badframe, command=badtext.yview)
    badscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)     

    badtext.config(yscrollcommand=badscrollbar.set)

    def fillbad():
        global badtext
        for i in range(50):
            badtext.insert(END, str(i) + "\n")

    badfillbutton = Button(root, command=fillbad, text="fill")
    badfillbutton.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def clearbad():
        global badtext
        badtext.delete(1.0, END)

    badclearbutton = Button(root, command=clearbad, text="clear")
    badclearbutton.grid(row=2, column=0)

    ###

    def fixyscrollcommand(lo, hi):
        global noyscroll, goodframe, goodscrollbar, goodtext

        start = float(lo)
        end = float(hi)

        # weird Windows bug
        if noyscroll != ((end - start) >= 1.0):
            goodscrollbar.destroy()
            goodscrollbar = Scrollbar(goodframe, command=goodtext.yview)
            goodscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)

        goodscrollbar.set(lo, hi)

        noyscroll = False
        if (end - start) >= 1.0:
            noyscroll = True

    goodframe = Frame(root)
    goodframe.grid(row=0, column=1)

    goodtext = Text(goodframe, yscrollcommand=fixyscrollcommand)
    goodtext.grid(row=0, column=0)

    goodscrollbar = Scrollbar(goodframe, command=goodtext.yview)
    goodscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
    noyscroll = True

    def fillgood():
        global goodtext
        for i in range(50):
            goodtext.insert(END, str(i) + "\n")

    goodbutton = Button(root, command=fillgood, text="fill")
    goodbutton.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def cleargood():
        global goodtext
        goodtext.delete(1.0, END)

    goodclearbutton = Button(root, command=cleargood, text="clear")
    goodclearbutton.grid(row=2, column=1)

    ###

    mainloop()
```